# Python dictionary and multiple dict[]

Tags: python, dictionary

So, for an assignment I would have to take user input such as 1146 and then get python to convert it to "one one four six"

So far I start with the dictionary

```
dict = { 1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three", 4:"four", 5:"five",
     6:"six", 7:"seven", 8:"eight", 9:"nine"};
```

then ask for inout

```
x = raw_input(("enter number: "))
y = x.split
```

I want to know how or if dict[y] could take a variable such as when y is split after user inputs it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't name your dicts `dict` because you're basically replacing the built-in constructor for the `dict` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't index into a dict using a list, but you could use a loop, list comprehension or generator expression. Something like this:

```
digits = {'1':'one', '2':'two', ...}
x = raw_input("enter number: ")
y = ' '.join(digits[number] for number in x)
```

Comment: from what I understand, after input, it takes a number like 12 and adds from the dictionary to the blank ' '. so adds one then adds two to 'one ' until the number is done?

Comment: @glors; the `...` that Jeremy added at the end of line one means, *continue this sequence* (as in, go to `9`, or `0` in this case). The second line, I think you get. The third line says; `''.join`. So Jeremy is bringing a `''` (i.e. empty) character between each part of: `digits[number] for number in x`. Start from `for number in x`. Then check out dictionaries as a datatype.

Answer (score 5):

A few hints:

1. Include `0: "zero"` in your dictionary.
2. The line

   ```
   y = x.split
   ```

   does not call the method `x.split` -- it simply assigns the method itself to `y`.
3. To get the characters of a string, you can iterate over it:

   ```
   for c in my_string:
       print c
   ```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply.
I have added the 0:"zero" to my dictionary
Should I be converting the input into int before I use them for program?

and I don't understand what should be iterated over

Comment: @Droogans: Do note that Sven was the one to add the homework tag. It's not like everyone else simply ignored a tag the poster attached.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. But...the OP has 8 rep, and uses a `raw_input` function call. You can't get much more obvious than that.

Comment: It also said "for an assignment"  ;)

Comment: @JeremyRoman: I added the tag because the OP said it is for an assignment.

Comment: I did miss that, and I didn't mean to be too snarky. I only meant that the homework tag was initially missing, which I do try to look for.